# What options do I have if I want to play a premade adventure, but don't have enough players?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, gm-techniques, gm-preparation

I have a fixed group of players that isn't going to change. Better to say, several "groups" of 1 to 3 mostly socially awkward friends who don't want to have people they don't know behind the table, which means that I will not be able to recruit more.

Most of them, except 1 or 2 players are new to RPGs, so I don't even know their playstyles, and I am considering an option to run a premade adventure, but as I have read on the internet, they typically require a given amount of players, and changing it causes balance problems.

What options to adjust the party do I have as a GM, what are their drawbacks and advantages?

Right now I am just learning the system (Pathfinder), and the reason of asking this question is that I want to know if I actually have viable options and can consider playing adventures designed for bigger parties, if I should better avoid them, or if I should avoid them at all cost, huh.

A good answer would contain a list of both good and bad options, with either a detailed description of pros and cons or links to those across RPG.SE.

Comment: Could you narrow this by including both A) the name of the adventure you plan to run and B) the exact number and natures of the players you do have (that is, their playstyles--one kills, one heals, etc.)?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Edited the answer. Most of them are new to RPGs, they don't really have playstyles yet. Not even computer RPGs -- so no real means of judging playstyles. I am just considering playing a premade adventure, didn't choose one yet, and I am thinking if it's viable in my case if the adventure would be initially designed for more players.

Comment: Until you pick an adventure and the players pick their characters, this will probably be too broad; that is, you're asking for a list of *general* strategies that may prove useful later?

Comment: Are you playing face to face on a tabletop, or over a web client like Roll20?